# Calling a method in a class which is not there in interface, using type bounds

Tags: java, oop, types, interface, type-bounds

I have the below interface which doesn't have any methods.

```
public interface IMetric {
}
```

I have an implementation of it in the following way.

```
public class PerfGauge implements IMetric  {

    public PerfGauge(String name, final Object gaugeSource) {

    }
    print() {
         System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

How can I call a method in the PerfGauge class having IMetric as its type? I believe this can be done through type bounds? If so can someone assist with an example?

What I want to do is,

```
 IMetric metric = new PerfGauge(name,source);
 metric.print();
```

Comment: Why not add `print` to `IMetric`?

Comment: If the method is not in the interface, you can only call it by casting the `metric` variable to the type of the implementing class.

Comment: the only way to do so is either including a method `print` in the `IMetric` `interface` or by using the `instanceof` operator to check if `metric` is an instance of `PerfGauge` and cast it as one as: `((PerfGauge)metric).print();`. Otherwhise the `metric` interface doesn´t know about the `print` method.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder there are many other implementations which have other methods. And this print is not there in those implementations. I need this interface though. For some internal requirements.

Comment: @Eran is it possible to do this using type bounds?

Comment: @KevinEsche any other ways of doing it than casting? I heard this can be achieved using type bounds. But its confusing what I was told.

Comment: I don't think type bounds relate to the above, at least not with just the context above.

Comment: *"there are many other implementations which have other methods"* Then I think you classify them into "printable" ones and "non-printable" ones, using either options 2 or 3 on my list.

Comment: Why would you want to use an interface when it doesn't describe the member you're trying to call? It's really unclear what your *actual* requirements are. Just saying "For some internal requirements" doesn't help to clarify that at all

Comment: On an other note, if you´d want `metric` to behave like a `PerfGauge`, why wouldn´t you want to define the variable `metric` as one, instead of defining it as `IMetric`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **can** call any method on any instance via reflection, but you shouldn't.

In your specific use case:

```
IMetric metric = new PerfGauge(name,source);
((IPrintable)metric).print();
```

you can just cast to `PerfGauge`:

```
IMetric metric = new PerfGauge(name,source);
((PerfGauge)metric).print();
```

...but that's not very satisfying.

I see these further options off-the-cuff:

1. Add `print` to `IMetric`, as you appear to need it where you have an `IMetric` reference to the instance.
2. Create a second indepedent interface, `IPrintable` or whatever, with `print`; and have `PerfGauge` implement that; then use `IPrintable` instead of `IMetric` in your usage location.

   Example below.
3. Tie `IPrintable` to `IMetric` (`public interface IPrintableMetric extends IMetric`) to create `IPrintableMetric` and use *that* in your usage location:

   ```
   IPrintableMetric metric = new PerfGauge(name,source);
   metric.print();
   ```

From the constraints you mention in a comment on the question, it sounds like an independent `IPrintable` may be the way to go:

```
public interface IPrintable {
    void print();
}

public class PerfGauge implements IMetric, IPrintable {

    public PerfGauge(String name, final Object gaugeSource) {

    }
    public void print() {
         System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

then either:

```
IPrintable metric = new PerfGauge(name,source);
metric.print();
```

or

```
IMetric metric = new PerfGauge(name,source);
((IPrintable)metric).print();
```

or if you're receiving an `IMetric` without context, then:

```
if (metric instanceof IPrintable) {
    ((IPrintable)metric).print();
}
```